# Can Azure Cosmos DB Change Feed be used to provide real-time functionality similar to what is offered by RethinkDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

To build real-time functionality similar to RethinkDB what would the high level server side design look like in Azure?

Using DocumentDB as the data store along with the Change Feed seems like the logical place to start but what's next? At first glance the Change Feed Processor library seems relevant to solving this problem but reading through [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) makes me think it's designed for something else - distributing workload.  Also, being unable to query/filter the Change Feed seems like an obstacle.

Here is an example from the [RethinkDB docs](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/):

> Suppose you have a chat application with multiple clients posting
>   messages to different chat rooms. You can create feeds that subscribe
>   to messages posted to a specific room:
>
> ```
> r.table('messages').filter(
>   r.row('room_id').eq(ROOM_ID)
> ).changes().run(conn, callback)
> ```

What I'm asking is how I might use DocumentDB along with the Change Feed to achieve something like this.  I am not looking for a complete solution, I am looking for a high level design strategy to move my thinking and experimenting in the right direction.

So, is building this type of functionality on top of DocumentDB doable (advisable) and if yes, what are the Azure "pieces" one would use?  What would this solution look like?

**Update**: Changed reference from Firebase to RethinkDB because it is more in line with what I am looking for (server side vs client talking directly to db).

**Note**: To those looking to close this question, I can't get much more specific at this time because this is where I'm at.  If you really feel this type of question is inappropriate for Stack Overflow, I would appreciate a suggestion as to where I might post it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change Feed gives all the changes to the document. Today, you can not subscribe to changefeed for *a particular event* or filter the feed. You have to filter the events in your functions.

Azure functions have a very nice integration with Change Feed. It simplifies your development.